# RIFF ICMT tag size doesn't seem to match data

Tags: c#, wav, riff

I am trying to read the data stored in an ICMT tag on a WAV file generated by a noise monitoring device.

The RIFF parsing code all seems to work fine, except for the fact that the ICMT tag seems to have data after the declared size. As luck would have it, it's the timestamp, which is the one absolutely critical piece of info for my application.

`SYN` is hex 16, which gives a size of 22, which is up to and including the NUL before the timestamp. The monitor documentation is no help; it says that the tag includes the time, but their example also has the same issue.

[image]

It is the last tag in the enclosing list, and the size of the list does include it - does that mean it doesn't need a chunk ID? I'm struggling to find decent RIFF docs, but I can't find anything that suggests that's the case; also I can't see how it'd be possible to determine that it was the last chunk and so know to read it with no chunk ID.

Alternatively, the ICMT comment chunk is the last thing in the file - is that a special case? Can I just get the time by reading everything from the end of the declared length ICMT to the end of the file and assume that will always work?

The current parser behaviour  is that it's being read after the channel / dB information as a chunk ID + size, and then complaining that there was not enough data left in the file to fulfil the request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it would still need its own ID. No, being the last thing in the file is no special case either. What you're showing here is malformed.

Your current parser errors correctly, as the next thing to be expected again is a 4 byte ID followed by 4 bytes for the length. The potential ID `_10:` is unknown and would be skipped, but interpreting `51:4` as DWORD for the length of course asks for trouble.

The device is the culprit. Do you have other INFO fields which use NULL bytes? If not then I assume the device is naive enough to consider a NULL the end of a string, despite producing himself strings with multiple NULLs.

Since I encountered countless files not sticking to standards I can only say your parser is too naive as well: it knows how long the encapsulating list is and thus could easily detect field lengths that would not fit anymore. And could ignore garbage like that. Or, in your case, offer the very specific option "add to last field".

Comment: In the end I got a reply back from the manufacturer that the behaviour is by design, so I just added the specific option as you suggested "if tag is this, length is actually this". Thanks!

Comment: "By design" - ask the manufacturer why he wants no software to be able to properly parse his files. My guess: he just doesn't care.

Comment: It's also my theory is that it works with their own bundled software and while not putting up actual barriers, they don't really care about making it easy for third party solutions.